# What is the name of the theme/plugin used for Wordpress Answers

Tags: themes

What is the name of the theme/plugin that is used here for "WordPress answers"?

thanks!

Comment: This is a **Meta** question...

Answer (score 2):

This site is not built on wordpress, or even in PHP. It's a .NET site built on the custom stackexchange framework.